# How set different font color for different binding element

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, multibinding

I am using Multibinding to set data in TextBlock. I want different color for different property binding.

Please see code for more details,

```
<StatusBar x:Name="messageBar">
      <StatusBarItem>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtStatusMessage" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red" Height="35">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConvertMultiple}"
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding ElementName="txtUserFriendlyName" 
                     Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>

            <Binding ElementName="txtXPathValue" 
                     Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent" />

            <Binding ElementName="cboTagName" 
                     Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

how can I give different font color for different Binding element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different Runs inside textblock and give different color.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtStatusMessage"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Height="35">
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=txtUserFriendlyName, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=txtXPathValue, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="White"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=cboTagName, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Green"/>
</TextBlock>
```